# Windows 7 detecting a device which is disabled in the BIOS

Tags: windows-7, bios

I have a PC with four ethernet ports and want only ethernet port 1 to be enabled.  So I went into the PC BIOS and disabled ethernet ports 2,3 and 4 and left port 1 enabled.

But then I booted into Windows 7 and ethernet ports 1,2,3 and visible in device manager.  Strangley no port 4.

Does windows 7 have the ability to detect hardware by bypassing the BIOS in some way?  Am I missing something possibly in the BIOS?

Comment: I guess you are missing something in bios. Check again

Comment: If bios does not do it, disable them in Device Manager.